# What does libgcc_s.so contain?

Tags: linux, libraries

I tried running objdump on the lib to figure it out without success. Is there a way to find out what a library does?

Comment: `objdump -T libgcc_s.so` gives you the shared object linker points. Presuming you know what `__gttf2` and the like mean, you should have no problem. (I expect that libgcc_s.so is atypically cryptic for an in this regard)

Comment: Possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414625/do-i-really-need-libgcc

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's [GCC's runtime librar](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html)y, which contains some low-level functions that GCC emits calls to (like `long long` division on 32-bit CPUs).

Part of this library is [required by the LSB](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libgcc-s.html).

Comment: +1 dumb old me, sometimes one just doesn't look in the obvious place

Comment: do you happen to know if a specific processor's EABI(e.g. ARM EABI) is implemented in that lib?

Comment: @celavek I'm not sure what you mean. AFAIK, current platform's ABI would be implemented, same as in other GCC runtime libs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

Comment: What if you use clang instead of gcc, would it still be linked in?

Comment: It can be, depending on the --rtlib= option to clang.